# How to convert a Dataframe into a List (Scala)?

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark, dataframe

I want to convert a Dataframe which contains Double values into a List so that I can use it to make calculations. What is your suggestion so that I can take a correct type List (i.e. Double) ?

My approach is this :

```
var newList = myDataFrame.collect().toList
```

but it returns a type **List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]** which I don't know what it is exactly!

Is it possible to forget that step and simply pass my Dataframe inside a function and make calculation from it? (*For example I want to compare the third element of its second column with a specific double. Is it possible to do so directly from my Dataframe?*)

At any cost I have to understand how to create the right type List each time!

**EDIT:**

Input Dataframe:

```
+---+---+ 
|_c1|_c2|
+---+---+ 
|0  |0  | 
|8  |2  | 
|9  |1  | 
|2  |9  | 
|2  |4  | 
|4  |6  | 
|3  |5  | 
|5  |3  | 
|5  |9  | 
|0  |1  | 
|8  |9  | 
|1  |0  | 
|3  |4  |
|8  |7  | 
|4  |9  | 
|2  |5  | 
|1  |9  | 
|3  |6  |
+---+---+
```

Result after conversion:

```
List((0,0), (8,2), (9,1), (2,9), (2,4), (4,6), (3,5), (5,3), (5,9), (0,1), (8,9), (1,0), (3,4), (8,7), (4,9), (2,5), (1,9), (3,6))
```

But every element in the List has to be Double type.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more with inputs and expected results ?

Comment: Hello! check again!

Answer (score 4):

You can cast the coulmn you need to `Double` and convert it to RDD and `collect` it

If you have data that cannot be parsed then you can use udf to clean before casting it to double

```
val stringToDouble = udf((data: String) => {
  Try (data.toDouble) match {
    case Success(value) => value
    case Failure(exception) => Double.NaN
  }
})

 val df = Seq(
   ("0.000","0"),
   ("0.000008","24"),
   ("9.00000","1"),
   ("-2","xyz"),
   ("2adsfas","1.1.1")
 ).toDF("a", "b")
  .withColumn("a", stringToDouble($"a").cast(DoubleType))
  .withColumn("b", stringToDouble($"b").cast(DoubleType))
```

After this you will get output as

```
+------+----+
|a     |b   |
+------+----+
|0.0   |0.0 |
|8.0E-6|24.0|
|9.0   |1.0 |
|-2.0  |NaN |
|NaN   |NaN |
+------+----+
```

To get `Array[(Double, Double)]`

```
val result = df.rdd.map(row => (row.getDouble(0), row.getDouble(1))).collect()
```

The result will be `Array[(Double, Double)]`

Comment: Hello! I understand the logic behind your approach but I am losing it on the practical side as I am very new to scala. What I understand here is that you create a DataFrame with data that is standar. In my situation the dataframe which I have to create comes from a dataset file (csv) and it won't be standar every time. So how can I cast a column of an existing DataFrame into Double?

Comment: Also when I run the "convert to rdd" command on my dataframe (without any cast changing) I get this error `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 333.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 333.0 (TID 333, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double`

Comment: In those cases you need to clean your data, need to remove nulls or remove some value that cannot be converted to Double and so on. It depends on your implementation. You can create a udf where you can clean all those things.

Comment: Yes the error is clear you need to cast the coulmn to Double `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double`

Comment: Oh ok! I understand! That means I have to do much more digging arround! Thank you for your respnse!

Comment: @ArisKantas I have added a sample udf please take a look. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
#Convert DataFrame to DataSet using case class & then convert it to list

#It'll return the list of type of your class object.All the variables inside the #class(mapping to fields in your table)will be pre-typeCasted) Then you won't need to #type cast every time.

#Please execute below code to check it-
#Sample to check & verify(scala)-

val wa = Array("one","two","two")
val wr = sc.parallelize(wa,3).map(x=>(x,"x",1))
val wdf = wr.toDF("a","b","c")
case class wc(a:String,b:String,c:Int)
val myList= wds.collect.toList
myList.foreach(x=>println(x))
myList.foreach(x=>println(x.a.getClass,x.b.getClass,x.c.getClass))
```

Comment: Hello! It gives me this error: `error: too many arguments for method println: (x: Any)Unit
myList.foreach(x=>println(x.a.getClass,x.b.getClass,x.c.getClass))`

Comment: Which version of spark you’re using? Or you can check only individual element data types using - myList.foreach(x=>println(x.a.getClass)) likewise you can check Data types for individual columns or concatenate them in single string (it’s just to check data types).

Answer (score -1):

```
myDataFrame.select("_c1", "_c2").collect().map(each => (each.getAs[Double]("_c1"), each.getAs[Double]("_c2"))).toList
```

Comment: What type of list does this return?

Comment: This approach takes one collumn of my DataFrame and pass it into a Sequence? How about taking all the collumns of my DataFrame? And can I use the Sequence the same way I would use a List?

Comment: yes same way as List and 

myDataFrame.select("column1", "column2").collect().map(each => (each.getAs[String]("column1"), each.getAs[String]("column2")) ).toList

You will get list of tuple here

Comment: Thank you! Now I want to ask, what type of elements will exist in this List? String or Double?

Comment: In this example, I cast both columns as String. You must cast according to your data frame. in this example, you will get the list of the tuple ( List[(String, String)] )

Comment: I have provided my Dataframe a the latest edit on my post. As you can see I have numbers so my result has to be Double. How to change your suggestion in order to have the result I want?

Comment: Please check my Answer now